# how to map the same key with two different behavior in vim?

Tags: vim, vi, keymapping

Okay here is my problem I want to find a way on how to map a key that have two different behaviors based on the number of hits.
so as an example let's suppose that I want to add a `;` at the end of the line when I hit the key `;` and if I hit it **twice** it will  be removed.

Note: the semicolon is only an example the main idea is how to toggle the key

Comment: The `;` is a wonder command to repeat the previous `f`, `t`, `F`, or `T`. I suggest you use a different key. See `:h ;`

Comment: you are right but as I am not using it too much so I can change its behavior to what is more suitable to me ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do, despite it being a bit nutty...

```
nnoremap ; :if(getline('.')[col('$')-2]==';')\|exe "norm $x"\|else\|exe "norm A;"\|endif<cr><cr>
```

It gets the last character of the current line (string indexing is 0-based, `col('$')` returns the 1-based column just past the end of line so that's why there's a `-2` in there), compares that to semicolon, and either removes or appends the last character from the line.

I don't know why it requires two `<CR>`s at the end. The `exe`s are because `norm` captures everything to the end of line so the bar doesn't separate "lines" otherwise.

**Edit for changing requirements:** :-)

If you want to ensure that one and only one semicolon appears at the end of a line and also handle trailing spaces (including spaces between semicolons), it's actually a lot easier than toggling the last semicolon if you don't need to keep the trailing spaces. This will also make sure that the one semicolon doesn't have any spaces before it, if you actually want to leave spaces before the semicolon remove the first `\s*`.

`nnoremap ; :s/\v\s*(;\s*)*$/;/<cr>`

If you still want to toggle but need to handle trailing spaces then we need to figure out what you intend to do with those trailing spaces. My preference is just to delete them so you can go on with the simpler things in life... Hook this up to a key if you want, I actually do it while handling BufWritePre in an `autocmd`.

`:%s/\s\*$//e`

Comment: it seems a little bit complicated especially with my current level in vim but it works. Thanks !

Comment: A bit shorter: `nnoremap <expr> ; getline(line('.')) =~ ';$' ? '$x' : "A;\<esc>"`. Note: this has the side effect of altering the unnamed register.

Comment: Both of these methods might modify the unnamed register. That can (and should) be fixed by adding `"_` between `$` and `x`.

Comment: This still have a problem with the trailing spaces at the end but I got the idea.

Comment: Ok, so you're changing the requirements. Editing answer to suit.

Comment: While writing this update I realized that you may not be looking for a toggle as initially presented but rather a full fix and the toggle seemed like a "simple" solution. With the power at your hands in Vim, often times providing a complete fix for the problem you're trying to solve is easier than something that requires manual intervention.

Comment: actually I found what I am looking for by creating a function to solve that and I tried to come back to your solution to see and to have another idea !

Answer (score 1):

```
nnoremap ; A;<esc>
nnoremap ;; $x
```

Note that this will delete the last char on your line no matter what it is. If you want it to only delete the last character if it is a semicolon, you could do this:

```
nnoremap ;; $hf;x
```

This works because the remap will stop running if the `f` command (find) fails, e.g. if there is no semicolon at the end of the line.

**Edit**:

```
nnoremap ; A;<esc>hh2f;xx
```

seems to do what you want. It's certainly not very neat, but it works.

Comment: This requires a timeout so I need to hit ;; within a second. Maybe I was not totally clear how can we do the check during the mapping.

Comment: Oh so it will delete the semicolon if it's there and add it if it's not there? So a toggle?

Comment: @Meninx See my edit.

Comment: close enough but it doesn't work for empty lines.